# wxWidgets/wxPython: Migrating from htmlWindow to Webview

Tags: python, webview, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have an app that uses htmlWindow and would like to migrate it to the new webview found in wx 2.9. However, I have learned there is no built-in method available to pass a JavaScript variable from the webpage back to the Python code. There is a RunScript method that allows one to send JavaScript to the page, but no method to retrieve an element id on a user click or any other user interaction.

My question is, is there any workaround to this? Is there any way to intercept, say, an alert call or anything else and get the data? The webview display is of not much value if one cannot receive data from user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the only way to get a return value from RunScript() is to use the page title hack.

e.g. somewhere in RunScript you set document.title to the value you wish to retrieve and get it into python with GetCurrentTitle(), if you wish you can reset the title after you have retrieved the data.

So if self.html is the webview

```
self.html.RunScript("""
    //javascript goes here
    // variable we wish to retrieve is called return_value
    document.title = return_value
    """)
r =  self.html.GetCurrentTitle()
```

If you want to initiate it from within the webview it can be done (as suggested in the link Robin posted) by overriding the wxEVT_COMMAND_WEB_VIEW_NAVIGATING so that when it receives a custom url scheme, e.g. retrievedata://data/.... it retrieves the data from the url and does whatever you want with it, making sure you call evt.Veto() at some point. You can then pass any data you wish by simply calling a suitable url from within javascript.

Totally untested code below (just to give you an idea of how it can be done)

```
def OnPageNavigation(self, evt):
    url = evt.GetUrl()
    if url.startswith("retrievedata://data/"):
         data = url[len("retrievedata://data/"):]
         evt.Veto()
         // Do whatever you want with the data
```

Alternatively you could use a combination of the two ideas and create a single url that when accessed calls GetPageTitle() and just make sure you set document.title before calling the page.

Comment: Thanks. I may be able to work both into my app. Hopefully, wx will have an official way to return data soon.

Answer (score 0):

There was recently some discussion on the wx-users mail list and a suggestion for a workaround for things like this.  I haven't tried it myself, but you may find it useful.  See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/wx-users/Pdzl7AYPI4I/discussion

Comment: Thanks, but these workarounds seem to be for buttons or links. I need to be able to get the id of an element (div, span, p, etc.) back to Python when the user clicks within in or even hovers over it. The JavaScript can return a variable, but I need a way to get the variable to the Python code.